# Fine tuning the agsm bibliography style, and adding links

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, harvard-style

Lovely day. I am quite new to LaTeX but picking things up fast. One area which is confusing me greatly is getting my bibliography to work just how I like it.

I have settled on the `agsm` style and the `natbib` citation management issue, but there are still some issues.

- The volume number of a journal is set in bold. (blue in pic)
  I want it to just be plain (un-bolded).
- The journal titles have apostrophes around them. (red in pic)
  I want to get rid of the apostrophes.

This image added highlights these problems.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8lM01.png]

Lastly, for the electronic copy, I would like it so the journal identifiers (DOIs) are highlighted blue, so you can click on them and it takes you to the website of the journal article. (green in pic)

Help on any / all of the above would be greatly appreciated. I have searched online for about 8 hours and finally need to ask the lords of TeX.

Edit: This is my bibliography code so far I forgot to add:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand\harvardyearleft{\unskip, }
\renewcommand\harvardyearright[1]{.} 
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{ref1}
\bibliography{bibFile}
\end{document}
```

Note - that `\renewcommand` I found from this forum; it gets rid of brackets around the `year` field which I didn't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the file `agsm.bst` and make a copy, say, `myagsm.bst`. Next, open the new file in a text editor of your choice and search for the following line:

```
{ volume embolden field.or.null
```

(It's on l. 357 in my copy of the file.) Change this line to

```
{ volume field.or.null
```

i.e., tell BibTeX *not* to render the volume number in bold.

Third, look for the line

```
    { format.title quote "title" output.check }
```

inside the function named `article`. (It's on l. 698 in my copy of the file.) Change it to

```
    { format.title "title" output.check }
```

i.e., tell BibTeX *not* to place (single) quotes around the title. Finally, save the new file, update the TeX filename database if necesssary (say, by running `texhash` if you use TeXLive or MacTeX), and start using the new bibliography style by issuing the command

```
\bibliographystyle{myagsm}
```

from now on.

I should note that this is all *extremely hack-ish*. What you really ought to do is to run the utility program `makebst`, which will pose lots and lots of questions on just how you want to set up your custom `.bst` file. This utility will then create a brand-new bibliography style file that is based on the answers you provided. To run this utility, at a command prompt type `latex makebst` and follow the prompts.

An important additional advantage of using the `makebst` utility is that it will let you set up exactly what you think should happen with the contents of a field called `doi`. This is something you simply can't do by hacking the file `agsm.bst` -- short of a complete rewrite of the entire file, of course -- because the `agsm` bibliography style is quite old and doesn't even recognize the contents of a field named `doi`.

Comment: Dude, that's amazing. Thanks so much! Only one thing - when I rename it myagsm it says the citations are undefined. But it works as long as I keep the name agsm (I made a backup agsm). I ran that texthash from CMD (windows), so not sure what that problem is. I will try a makebst, but this so far is pretty much perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveHatcher - delighted that the proposed changes work for you. About getting the new file (myagsm.bst) recognized by TeX and friends: be sure to save the new file in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution; if nowhere else is available, just save it to the directory where `agsm.bst` is housed. Then run `texhash` (not `texthash`). If you use MikTeX, you'll need to click on "Update FNDB" in the main "Settings" window.

Comment: Thanks a lot. my suggestion is if you are using Texstudio after changing the modifications, please remove the `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` in your texstudio and run it. then after change to `\bibliographystyle{myagsm}` then run it. It will work.